# Removing all characters but letters in a string

Tags: java, string, character, punctuation

If I have a string `"ja.v_,a"`, how can I remove all non-letter characters to output `"java"`? I have tried `str = str.replaceAll("\\W", "" )`, but to no avail.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: remove/replace `[^a-z]`? (i.e. all non-letters `a..z` symbols)

Comment: I would use a for loop that checks every character. if it is a char, I would concatenate to a string. Character.isAlphabetic() is a starting point

Comment: How are you trying to remove them? Are you using the result of `str.replaceAll(...)`, or just invoking it as a statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you try this one?

```
System.out.println("ja.v_,a".replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "")) //java
```

Answer (score 4):

I would like to refer to [this article](http://javacodegeeks.com/2017/01/forget-iso-8859-1.html) and quote it:

> Regex examples and tutorials always give you the [a-zA-Z0-9]+ regex to "validate alphanumeric input". It is built-in in many validation frameworks. And it is so utterly wrong. This is a regex that must never appear anywhere in your code, unless you have a pretty good explanation. Yet, the example is ubiquitous. Instead, the right regex is [\p{L}0-9]+

So in your case it would be:

```
str.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}]", "");
System.out.println("ja.v_,a".replaceAll("[^\\p{L}]", ""));
System.out.println("сл-=о-_=во!".replaceAll("[^\\p{L}]", ""));
```

Where `\p{L}` is the Unicode definition of a "letter".

Comment: The statement `str.replaceAll("[^\p{L}]", "");` is useless. You need to use the result somehow.

Comment: @AndyTurner that is true, my point was that in 2017 `"a-z"` pattern would not be the best solution for a good developer to get used to. The rationale is set out in the article which I referred to.

Comment: This is an important answer. I would only add the explanation that `\p{L}` is the Unicode definition of a "letter".

Comment: And according to [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop) under title "Unicode Categories", it is better to use `\P{M}\p{M}*+` to match 1 or more Unicode characters, because letters with diacritics may be encoded in different way: `You should now understand why \P{M}\p{M}*+ is the equivalent of \X. \P{M} matches a code point that is not a combining mark, while \p{M}*+ matches zero or more code points that are combining marks. To match a letter including any diacritics, use \p{L}\p{M}*+. This last regex will always match à, regardless of how it is encoded. ...`

Answer (score 1):

```
String test= "ja.v_,a";

int len=test.length();

String alphaString="";

for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
     if (Character.isLetter(test.charAt(i))) {
         alphaString=alphaString+test.charAt(i);
     }
}

System.out.println(alphaString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "ja.v_,a";
s = s.replaceAll("[^a-z]", "");
System.out.println(s);

>java
```